# Function only checks last item in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function where i validate the user submitted emails. I do that by comparing the user email to every valid email domain. I store the user submitted emails in an array and i store the valid email domains also in an array. The problem is when using the function it only checks if the last value in the user array is valid and not the elements before it.

My function:

```
handelTeamError = () => {
    var array = []; //user emails get put in here 
    var emailcheck = EmailDomeinen(); //array with valid email domains
    const emailrow = this.state.rows.map(x => array.push(x.email)); //every email that user submitted

    //if user submitted nothing function will return false; user can't continue
    if(!emailrow){
        this.setState(() => ({tlemailError: true}));
        return false;
    }else{
        for(let i = 0; i < emailcheck.length; i++){
            let email = emailcheck[i]; //get all the valid emails
            for(let j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                let res = array[j].split("@", 1).toString(); //checks if user typed more than only the email domain
                if(!array[j].endsWith("@" + email)){ //if the user value ends with @ and a valid email domains
                    this.state.rows.map( x => x.tlEmailError = true); //error state = true
                }else{
                    if(res){
                        this.state.rows.map( x => x.tlEmailError = false); //error state = false
                        return true; // user can continue 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: `const emailrow = this.state.rows.map(x => array.push(x.email))` looks suspicious. You can simply do `const array = this.state.rows.map(x => x.email);` that will return an array of emails.

Comment: state has nothing to do with the checking functionality. That state is only there so the program knows it has to add a certain styling. @baklazan

Comment: `return true; // user can continue` - you are out of your loops and the whole function, the first time it reaches this line - sure that’s what you want?

Comment: Btw., I would perhaps change the order of those loops - right now you are doing the splitting at the @ for each email address for each single domain you check against, whereas if you did it the other way around - loop over email addresses entered by the user, and inside loop over valid domains, you would have to do this splitting only once per address. Might be micro-optimization, but still …

Comment: Do you have a `tlEmailError` for each email ? or is it a general property in your state ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're hoping to achieve with `this.state.rows.map( x => x.tlEmailError = true)`. If you're trying to set value of `tlEmailError` to `true` in state you should be using `this.setState` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems with your approach.

first of all `emailrow`  looks like it will always be an array (either empty or filled) so `if(!emailrow){` will always return `false`. You should use `if(!emailrow.length){`

Then you algorithm seems to be checking if each of the user emails ends with **all** the valid domains, which it understandably cannot. Your outer loop should be the user emails and your inner should try to find if one of the valid domains matches it.

Finally you seem to be trying to modify the state inside the `this.state.rows` directly instead of using the `setState` function which is the correct way.

So, a refactored version could be

```js
// this assumes that you have a sigle tlEmailError property in your state 
// and not one for each email
handelTeamError = () => {
  const validDomains = EmailDomeinen(); //array with valid email domains
  const userEmails = this.state.rows.map(row => row.email); //every email that user submitted

  // check if all emails are valid
  const allValid = userEmails.every(email => {
    const isValid = email.indexOf('@') > 0,
      userDomain = email.split('@')[1];

    return (isValid && validDomains.some(domain => domain === userDomain));
  });

  const result = userEmails.length && allValid;

  this.setState({
    tlEmailError: result
  });

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside: since you're alreay using `map` you could decrease your code footprint using another couple of JS array methods: [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const state = [{ name: 'bob', email: 'bob@gmail.com'}, { name: 'dan', email: 'dan@yahoo.com'},{ name: 'tree', email: 'tree@tree.com'},{ name: 'pete', email: 'pete@aol.com'}];
const emailCheck = ['aol.com', 'gmail.com'];

const array = state.reduce((arr, cur) => {
  const domain = cur.email.split('@')[1];
  emailCheck.includes(domain) ? cur.emailError = true : cur.emailError = false;
  return arr.concat(cur);
}, []);

console.log(array);
```